# $.extend() not merging options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin with options such as

```
$.growl.default_options = {
    allow_dismiss: true,
    position: {
        from: "top",
        align: "right"
    },
    offset: 20,
    spacing: 10,
    z_index: 1031,
    fade_in: 400,
    delay: 5000,
    template: {
        icon_type: 'class',
        container: '<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-3 alert">',
        dismiss: '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>',
        title: '<strong>',
        title_divider: '',
        message: ''
    }
});
```

When I call the program using the following options

```
$.growl("I am a Message!", {
    position: {
        align: 'left'
    },
    template: {
        container: '<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-3 alert">'
    }
});
```

In the plugin I do the following

```
options = $.extend({}, $.growl.default_options, options);
```

and than `options` is

```
$.growl.default_options = {
    allow_dismiss: true,
    position: {
        align: "right"
    },
    offset: 20,
    spacing: 10,
    z_index: 1031,
    fade_in: 400,
    delay: 5000,
    template: {
        container: '<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-3 alert">'
    }
});
```

Why does `template` only have one variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a deep (recursive) extend :

```
options = $.extend(true, {}, $.growl.default_options, options);
```

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) :

> The merge performed by $.extend() is not recursive by default; if a
>   property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be
>   completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second
>   or subsequent object. The values are not merged. This can be seen in
>   the example below by examining the value of banana. However, by
>   passing true for the first function argument, objects will be
>   recursively merged.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that my first time reading though, I just found it and was coming to close this when I saw it was already answered. haha. This works now.